# What is this .txt file in All Users of my PC?

Tags: filesystems, dll, users, multiple-users

I have come across an entry on my Lenovo ThinkPad laptop in Computer>System(C)>Users>All Users that I need an explanation for, as in what Log file was being created on 08/05/18, Removing ASPI, etc?  I need to know everything basically about what was being done on my laptop 08/05/2018 according to this DIFxInstallLog.txt
Here is an image of the log:
[image]

Comment: It appears to be a log file of a device you added. The All Users folder is a Hidden Folder and it is empty on my Lenovo machines (laptops and desktop)

Comment: Hi John, when you say device, do you mean literally or could you mean a sd card for example?  Only, I am at a loss with this.  It mentions CDROM in the log,  Does that have any bearing on the matter, do you think?

Comment: GEAR Software appears to be a legitimate software company. They create a CD/DVD recording engine that can be embedded in other software. Did you have iTunes installed in the past?

Comment: Also, big ask here - what was the device being asked to do, is that shown from the log at all?

Comment: Yes, iTunes is installed if rarely used on my laptop

Comment: I note this all takes less than 1 minute to complete.  in my experience, iTunes is clumpy and takes way longer, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I use iTunes with my iPhone but it does not go in All Users

Comment: Thanks for your input and time. Ii will look into GEAR Software and iTunes. Cheers.

Comment: @Vesper007 - The driver was being installed that’s it

Answer (score 1):

This is an artifact of a Gear driver install.  Gear Software licenses drivers for CD/DVD recording, etc., to companies wanting to add this functionality to their software.

In many cases, this was caused by an install of iTunes, but it could have been any number of music apps.

In installing its drivers, it sometimes needs to replace (uninstall) other drivers.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I am starting to see a pattern here and the pattern is iTunes. Thanks for your input.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3193348

Comment: Thanks Moab.  I agree, seems like an iTune install.